# Styled navigation with hidden links

Tags: html, css, seo

My main navigation on [shantiyoga.ca](http://www.shantiyoga.ca) is a stack of images with the text content of their anchor tag hidden

```
<li><a class="schedule" href="/schedule"><span class="hide">shanti yoga studio class schedule</span></a></li>
```

What is the best practice for hidden links in terms of SEO?

I have read Google's [General Guidelines](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=66353) and I'm wondering if there is a penalty besides being blacklisted, which I am not. Does hiding the content of my anchor tags affect my site in a negative way? Or is google clever enough to see the way things are set up and let it be?

I also thought [this article](http://searchengineland.com/google-vows-to-look-at-deceptive-cloaking-techniques-59802) had some interesting information

**Edit** - My current setup:

```
<a class="schedule" 
   id="{% ifequal current 'schedule' %}active{% endifequal %}" 
   href="/schedule"><span class="hide">class schedule</span></a>


a.schedule {
    background: url(../images/layout/nav/shanti-yoga-studio-schedule.jpg) no-repeat;        
    display: block;     
    height: 48px;
}

a.schedule:hover {
    background-position: -207px 0;  
}

#active {
    background-position: -414px 0;
}
```

Comment: Not really a direct answer to your question, but you could consider looking into implementing a custom font face through Google Web Fonts or a similar method, to avoid the issue entirely. However, that said, I've seen your general technique used quite a few times, but it's usually by positioning the text off screen, rather than using an explicit `display: none`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you have it now is a little clunky.

Instead of using a `span` with `visibility:hidden;` and a class that describes one specific style, a more semantic way that is also better for people using screen readers and theoretically search engines would be to use a very high negative `text-indent`:

`a { text-indent:-9999px; background-image:url(classes.png); }`

You don't even need an superfluous `span` this way. So if, in the future, you decide to change the design, the markup is much more flexible.

Comment: Thanks for your input. Are there any repercussions on mobile devices for negative indents of that size?  I could see this being an issue if a device renders the page to include all visible content - zooming out -9999px to fit the link on the screen?

Comment: I really don't think there are any problems with mobile. I see this technique in the wild all the time and have never had any problems myself.

Comment: It appears to be working - I will probably poke around a bit more and then implement your suggestion. thanks

Comment: How about negative margins creating a horizontal scroll?

Comment: I've never seen negative anything to the *left* of the document cause scroll. I'm not sure why though.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you're not trying to mislead users you really don't have anything to worry about. Image replacement is a well-plumbed pattern that is used widely. There is accessibility to consider though, so hide the text by moving it offscreen (with negative margin/text-indent or positioning it absolutely offscreen - do not use `display:none`) so screenreader users have something to navigate by.

Answer (score 0):

Does hiding the content of my anchor tags affect my site in a negative way?

I believe this answers that question perfectly:
http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=66353

Hope this helps!